# Ruby one liners -- trying to comprehend single line of ruby code that has an assignment, two equality tests, a ternary operator, and an && operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ternary-operator

In several railscasts, Ryan Bates uses this custom 'sortable' helper in conjunction with several helper methods (http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns). I'll just show you my doctored version.

The 'sortable' helper method looks like this (I've modified it for my own purposes, but the fundamental logic is the same)

```
def sortable(column, params, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  direction = column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params) && YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction)
end
```

I am baffled and overwhelmed by this line in the above: `direction = column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params) && YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"`.

Even if I did know all the syntactic, algebra-like (makes me think of the div/mult-first, addition/sub-second rules, etc) rules require to follow this single line, I still might not have the necessary ruby knowledge (the "truthiness" operators) to fully understand whats going on here. What I'm asking for is a walkthrough. For starters, my fuses are kind of blown right to begin with, with the `direction = column == ...` bit. But then I lose all understanding later down the line when **another** equality operator and a ternary operator step in.

in case you're wondering, sort_column & sort_direction are YearlyDerivative class methods (they don't really have to be there, I just needed to call them from different places so it worked out ok)

```
def self.sort_column(p)
  YearlyDerivative.column_names.include?(p[:sort]) ? p[:sort] : "revenue_usd_mil_derivative"
end

def self.sort_direction(p)
  %w[asc desc].include?(p[:direction]) ? p[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

That **single line** (`direction = column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params) && YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"`) contains one assignment, two equality operators, one && operator and a ternary operator. Of course, including the outside called methods, it uses 3 ternary operators but I have no problem understanding that.

Thanks for your patience. I'm hoping that understanding this brings me and other SO readers/searchers some unexpected programming insight.

Comment: I fully understand these operators by themselves, but its the oneliner bit that confuses me for the most part. At the same time, I always like to find programming shortcuts, and one liners in ruby are legendary for that.

Comment: You're over-thinking it. It's simply a compound conditional used to drive a ternary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my option, this is one of those attempts at being clever by consolidating
some logic into one line, that really shouldn't have been done. The real end
result is it's confusing and would lead to harder to maintain code because it
slows down the maintainer as they figure out what it's doing:

```
direction = column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params) && YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc".
```

Breaking it apart:

```
if (
  (column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params)) &&
  (YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc")
)
  direction = "asc" 
else
  direction = "desc"
end
```

In Ruby we can also simplify that a little more while retaining readability and comprehensability:

```
direction = if (
              (column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params)) &&
              (YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc")
            )
              "asc" 
            else
              "desc"
            end
```

It could even have been written like this, which is effectively a single-line as far as Ruby is concerned, but it remains easier to understand than the original one-line code because of the use of parenthesis to break the logic into chunks:

```
direction = (
  (column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params)) &&
  (YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc")
) ? "asc" : "desc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, step by step:

1. Set `direction` to the result of the following statement
2. Whether `column` is equal to `YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params)`
3. If (2) is true, return the rest of the line
4. If `YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc"` is true, return `"asc"`, else `"desc"`.

Or this (roughly) equivalent code:

```
if(column == YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params))
  if(YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc")
    direction = "asc"
  else
    direction = "desc"
  end
else
  false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no trouble to understand the call queue with ternary operator encapsulated in the method, I’d suggest you to disassemble the one-liner and then assemble it back:

```
def func1
  column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params)
end
def func2 
  YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"
end
direction = func1 && func2
```

Now let’s assemble it back:

```
#           ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ func1 ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓    ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ func2 ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ 
direction = (column == YearlyDerivative.sort_column(params)) && (YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc")
```

The braces above may be easily omitted according to the [operator precedence table](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence#Operator_Precedence_Table).

Furthermore, now you can get rid of functions in honour of total one-liner:

```
direction = column == (YearlyDerivative.column_names.include?(p[:sort]) ? p[:sort] : "revenue_usd_mil_derivative") && %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc") == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: BTW, I totally agree with the Tin Man’s comment above. Weird one-liner is much worse than pretty 10-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually switched my code out to the following

```
def sortable(column, params, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  if YearlyDerivative.test_column(params) && YearlyDerivative.sort_direction(params) == "asc"
    direction = "desc"
  else
    direction = "asc"
  end
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction)
end
```

notice the sort_column method has been changed out for the test_column method, which I find more logical.

```
def self.test_column(p)
  YearlyDerivative.column_names.include?(p[:sort]) ? true : false
end
```

the sort_column method is still used by the the 'sort' class method (below)

```
def self.sort(params); p = params
  order(sort_column(p) + " " + sort_direction(p))
end
```

** It looks like the first part of the 2-part conditional requirement in the original sortable helper method was useless. It returned true no matter what as far as the && operator was concerned.

```
def sort_column(p)
  ["a", "b", "c"].include?(p[:sort]) ? p[:sort] : "is it true or false?"
end
bad_params = {:sort => "d"}
x = true
if sort_column(bad_params) && x
  puts "hmm"
else; puts "it implied false"
end
#=> "hmm"
```

The above nature-of-ruby tests led me to create the test_column method.

Comment: `direction = nil` isn't needed. In addition, don't use `;` to join lines. It is not idiomatic in Ruby, nor does it improve readability. Readability was your reason for your question in the first place, but practices like that reduce it. Go for clarity and easily understood code, conciseness is important but not at the cost of maintainability.

Comment: Don't do that. Take the time to write code you'd want potential employers to see. They're all over this site.

Comment: Are you saying to not use this simplified helper? It does the same thing and I like the legibility, personally.